# Java AES Decrypting hex

Tags: java, aes

I'm working on a project where I need to decrypt AES encryption in Java. For testing, I've used an online calculator to encrypt "Hello World" with the key "0123456789ABCDEF" and an empty IV "0000000000000000". I'm having problems decrypting this in Java.

```
    String keyHex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    String ivHex = "0000000000000000";
    String inputHex = "ED488015821C37D59CBA611B19A8EAF3";

    // Hex to byte arrays
    var keyBytes = hexToByte(keyHex);
    var inputBytes = hexToByte(inputHex);
    var ivBytes = hexToByte(ivHex);

    // Add padding to key
    var paddingKey = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0, paddingKey,0, keyBytes.length);

    // Add padding to iv
    var paddingIV = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(ivBytes, 0, paddingIV,0, ivBytes.length);

    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(paddingIV);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(paddingKey, "AES");

    String alg = "AES/CBC/NoPadding";
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(alg);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

    byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(original));
    String s = new String(original);
    System.out.println("Decrypted: " + s);
```

It gives the wrong output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1XjK.png)

One of my guesses is that I'm using wrong padding for the key/IV, but if I'm not adding padding it complains about the key not being the correct length.

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: I wonder if the tool you used took the key as a string rather than hex string, as the string '0123456789ABCDEF' is only 8 bytes when transformed from hex to byte array... So it's basically what you said :). The code looks ok and I've never, ever had to 'pad' an AES key in the past... so I would put my money there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've tried using .getBytes() instead but still wrong output. I think I'm going to try Base64 encoding since I think cipher uses that format.